# SignalR MVC crossdomain $.connection is undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

i'm having a pretty annoying issue with signalr in my mvc application.

I've got a signalr server in it's own project under (localhost:49648)

The application that is calling said server references the following from it:

```
<script src="http://localhost:49648/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script> 
<script src="http://localhost:49648/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

JQuery 2.1.4 is also referenced at the top of my application (so i've ruled out script overlapping)

Essentially, **$.connection** is always returned as **undefined** in MVC only. The required files are indeed loaded when i check the source files (debug). The server does accept cross-domain requests. I've also tried running the exact code written in the MVC view in a standard html file at the project root and it works without issue.

Any idea why MVC doesn't recognize the connection?

Comment: Can you navigate to http://localhost:49648/signalr/hubs in your browser? 
Also, is the project that has your hub running?
$.connection returns a promise, are you chaining a done callback to your connection? 

More code would help with being able to see what the possible issue might be

Comment: Everything was running fine, it was really because of the dual jquery scripts loaded in the masterpage layout (i didn't write it) that kept overwriting signalr. (i figured it out 20 minutes ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all this running around, the preformated master page layout created by my colleagues referenced JQuery twice, once at top  (which i saw) and one at bottom (which i didn't). I created a bottomScript section at the bottom of the master page and loaded signalr in there and now everything works great.

Comment: Yep I have made this mistake too!